# trouble installing numpy for python3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am running on ubuntu with several python versions installed. What am I missing?

```
user@serverA:/folderB$ python3.9 -m pip install numpy
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (1.13.3)
user@serverA:/folderB$ python3.9 logs_unifier.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/folderB/logs_unifier.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
user@serverA:/folderB$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `python3.9 -m pip install -U --user numpy`. `-U` means upgrade, and `--user` means it'll install in your user folder, not the system folder - it just gets rid of that message.

NumPy is up to version 1.22, so it's possible that `pandas` just doesn't work with the old version.

Comment: Thanks, wdyt about this ?`
python3.9 -m pip -U --user numpy

Usage:   
  /usr/bin/python3.9 -m pip <command> [options]

no such option: -U`

Comment: I made a stupid mistake - I forgot to include `install` after the word `pip`. Check my answer now, it's correct.